# jQuery putting a variable in a variable containing a html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this variable: `var company;` to work in the next line.

```
var newcomp ='<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-database=""><script>var company;</script></button>';
var newcomp ='<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-database="">'+ company + '</button>';
```

the script tags where the problem.

In the future i will try to improve my questions. Thx for the help guys.

Comment: You should really edit your question and descripe what you want to do! Acually all are just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<script>` tag inside your `button` and escape `company`:

```
var company = $("#newCompAdd").val();
var newcomp = '<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-database="">' + company + '</button>';
```

Your full example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document.body).on("click", "#formAddNewCompanySave", function() {
    var company = $("#newCompAdd").val();
    alert(company);
    var newcomp = '<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-database="">' + company + '</button>';
    $('#companylist').append(newcomp);

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "addCompany.php",
      data: {}
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var company = "abc";

    var newcomp ='<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-database=""><script>' + company + '</script></button>';
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my unclear questions. I am pretty new to this. I am adding a new company with jquery. the value of the input field will be stored in var company. var newcomp adds a new company to the list. But what i want is to give the new company the name that is stored in var company;

Answer (score 0):

```
var newcomp ='<button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-database="">'+ company + '</button>';
```

the script tags where the problem.

In the future i will try to improve my questions. Thx for the help guys.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear.
But you can send variable value to jquery like this :

```
"<a href='#' class='your function name' data-database='{$company}'>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"></button>
 </a>"
```

and you can get value of variable with jquery like this :

```
function yourfunctionname(database)}{ var newcomp = database; }
```